# How to free memory for Boost Multi-Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, boost-multi-array

How to free allocated memory for a Boost multi-array?

There is no `clear`, or `free`, or `delete` member function in its interface. I have a 3-dimensional array, and currently, I am doing resize to `[0,0,0]` extents to free up memory. But, is there a better way to free memory for my 3D array?

Comment: Multi, an alternative to Boost.MultiArray has a member called `.clear()` that does exactly that: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/README.md#change-sizes-extents . (I wrote the library precisely because BMA didn't have have an standard interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resizing to zero extents sounds entirely satisfactory and reasonable.

After all, this is /also/ the only interface available to allocate the memory in the first place.

If you prefer, you could make a free function to do the jobs hiding the implementation detail.